# What WYSIWYG works well with jQuery and Ruby on Rails 3.1 (Sprockets)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

I am having trouble making any "common" WYSIWYG work with Rails. We even had to do one ourselves with RedCloth for the moment.

I tried to use [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) but couldn't make it work. Also tried [nicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) which worked but only when you called the online library (and also looks abandoned).

Has anyone worked with a good WYSIWYG that is jQuery and Rails 3.1 (Sprockets) friendly?

Comment: tinymce looks recent and should work. What kind of error did you receive?

Comment: It is recent but it is really hard to implement. The idea is to have a gem or something that works for rails 3.1 (as they exist for rails 3).

Comment: From the documentation it should be really easy. What step did not work?

Comment: is easy when you load it in your public folder... but i am asking for a gem or library that works with the assets pipeline

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) in my Rails 3.1 app.

Just throw the folder into you lib/assets/javascripts and whenever you need it reference it like this:

```
= javascript_include_tag "ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
```

And in javascript:

```
:javascript
  $(function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'input',
      {
        // Optional params:
        skin : 'office2003',
        height: '700px'
      });
  })
```

Comment: Note: To work on Heroku I found that I had to add this to the top of ckeditor.js: var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor/';

Comment: It works great for me too. THanks for the tip. Switching away from tiny_mce

Comment: If you need multiple ckeditor fields on one page, go for aloha-editor or mercury editor instead.

Mercury limits browsers to non-IE for editing, but that usually isn't a problem...

Answer (score 8):

After struggling with this issue for quite awhile, I came up with a solution for using the standard tinyMCE with Rails 3.1 and the asset pipeline.

1. I started with the tinyMCE jQuery package.
2. Create a directory in vendor for tinyMCE: `/vendor/assets/javascripts/tiny_mce`
3. Place only `jquery.tinymce.js` inside of `/vendor/assets/javascripts/tiny_mce`
4. Place the remaining tinyMCE files in a directory in your `/public/javascripts` folder, inside of a directory called `tiny_mce`
5. Add tinyMCE to your `application.js` like so:

   ```
   //=require jquery
   ...
   //=require tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js
   ```
6. I initialize tinyMCE in my `application.js` as well, and set a `script_url` path to tell tinyMCE that it's supporting files now live in my `public/javascripts/tiny_mce` directory:

   ```
   $('.tinymce').each(function(i){
   $(this).tinymce({
     script_url : '/javascripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
      ...
   ```

That should work. Now you are using the asset pipeline to load tinyMCE, and serving the supporting assets and javascripts from the public directory.

Answer (score 3):

The Mercury Editor looks promising. I'm planning to try it on my next rails project.

http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/

Comment: I'm looking for something more simple, that looks great though.

Comment: You're lucky by don't having any ie customer

Comment: There is a good Railscasts [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor) that shows how to set Mercury up.

Answer (score 0):

Try MarkitUp

http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/

Comment: It looks great but unfortunately it is not a WYSIWYG Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Luuf already mentioned Aloha-Editor. Though it's still under heavy development it looks quite promising.

Just put a aloha-config.js file anywhere in your asset path, the aloha-files goes to (i.e.) vendor/assets.

Example config:

```
    (function(window, undefined) {
        if (window.Aloha === undefined || window.Aloha === null) {
        var Aloha = window.Aloha = {};
            }

    Aloha.settings = {
      logLevels: {'error': true, 'warn': true, 'info': true, 'debug': false,    'deprecated': true},
      baseUrl: "/assets/lib",
      errorhandling: false,
      plugins: false
    };
    })(window);
```

The line "baseUrl" is most important. Setting it to /assets/lib seems to ensure compability with the asset pipeline.

Haven't tried concatenation yet, will post a comment when I know how it behaves.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Aloha Editor

http://aloha-editor.org/

It's tough between that & Mercery - but Aloha has a nicer "feel" and it has wider browser support.